# Encrypting with Perl CBC and decrypting with PHP mcrypt

Tags: php, perl, mcrypt

I have an encrypted string that was encrypted with Perl Crypt::CBC (Rijndael,cbc). The original plaintext was encrypted with encrypt_hex() method of Crypt::CBC.

```
$encrypted_string = '52616e646f6d49567b2c89810ceddbe8d182c23ba5f6562a418e318b803a370ea25a6a8cbfe82bc6362f790821dce8441a790a7d25d3d9ea29f86e6685d0796d';
```

I have the 32 character key that was used.

mcrypt is successfully compiled into PHP, but I'm having a very hard time trying to decrypt the string in PHP. I keep getting gibberish back.

If I unpack('H*', $encrypted_string), I see 'RandomIV' followed by what looks like binary.

I can't seem to correctly extract the IV and separate the actual encrypted message. I know I'm not providing my information, but I'm not sure where else to start.

```
$cipher = 'rijndael-256';
$cipher_mode = 'cbc';

$td = mcrypt_module_open($cipher, '', $cipher_mode, '');

$key = '32 characters'; // Does this need to converted to something else before being passed?
$iv = ??  // Not sure how to extract this from $encrypted_string.
$token = ?? // Should be a sub-string of $encrypted_string, correct?

mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$clear = rtrim(mdecrypt_generic($td, $token), '');
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td); 
mcrypt_module_close($td);

echo $clear;
```

Any help, pointers in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

I think the IV to use is just generated randomly by CBC::Crypt. If I'm right and reading the doc correctly, it's the 32 first bytes of the unpacked string.

Try this with the good key :

```
$cipher = 'rijndael-256';
$cipher_mode = 'cbc';

$td = mcrypt_module_open($cipher, '', $cipher_mode, '');

$key = '32 characters'; // Does this need to converted to something else before being passed?

$unpacked = pack('H*', '52616e646f6d49567b2c89810ceddbe8d182c23ba5f6562a418e318b803a370ea25a6a8cbfe82bc6362f790821dce8441a790a7d25d3d9ea29f86e6685d0796d');


$iv = substr($unpacked, 0, 32);
$token = substr($unpacked, 32);

mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$clear = rtrim(mdecrypt_generic($td, $token), '');
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td); 
mcrypt_module_close($td);

echo $clear;
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for the salted mode of Crypt::CBC, not the randomIV mode, but this is the page I ended up on when searching for a solution so other might also.

When using this perl code:

```
  my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
                -key    =>  $password,
                -cipher => 'Rijndael',
                -salt => 1,
                -header => 'salt',
              ) || die "Couldn't create CBC object";
  $string = $cipher->encrypt_hex($input);
```

(or even without salt and header which have these values by default)
Perl will create a hash that is meant to be OpenSSL compliant.
I did not find any PHP method that knows how to read this, so here is my own PHP version of the decoding found in CBC.pm.
I extract key and iv, and then I let mcrypt finish the job.

```
function cred_decrypt($input, $password)
{
  /************************* Inspired by Crypt/CBC.pm *******************************/
  $input = pack('H*', $input);
  if (substr($input, 0, 8) != 'Salted__') {
    die("Invalid hash header, expected 'Salted__', found '".substr($input, 0, 8)."'");
  }
  $salt   = substr($input, 8, 8);
  $input  = substr($input, 16);

  $key_len  = 32;
  $iv_len   = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

  $data = '';
  $d    = '';
  while (strlen($data) < $key_len+$iv_len) {
    $d = md5($d . $password . $salt, TRUE);
    $data .= $d;
  }
  $key  = substr($data, 0, $key_len);
  $iv   = substr($data, $key_len, $iv_len);
  /**********************************************************************************/

  return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0\n\3");
}
```

Note : the rtrim was needed in my case, it might eat ending newlines if any.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work either. I have a feeling that Perl's CBC::Crypt does things a lot differently than PHP's mcrypt functions. I've been trying to find the source code for the mcrypt functions in my PHP directory to compare them, but no luck yet.